# HTML button communicating with Node server + Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

When a user clicks an html button (#new) I want to store their socket.id into an array (userQueue) on my node server but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this. Do I need to set up a post request or is there a way through socket.io?

App.js (Server):

```
// App setup
var express      = require('express'),
   socket        = require('socket.io'),
   app           = express(),
   bodyParser    = require("body-parser");

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
   console.log('listening to requests on port 3000');
});
var io = socket(server);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static('public'));

// Room Logic
var userQueue = [];

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
   console.log('made socket connection', socket.id);

   socket.on('chat', function(data) {
      io.sockets.emit('chat', data);
   });

   socket.on('typing', function(data) {
      socket.broadcast.emit('typing', data);
   });

});
```

Chat.js (client side):

```
// Make connection
 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');


// Query DOM
var message  = document.getElementById('message');
    handle   = document.getElementById('handle'),
    btn      = document.getElementById('send'),
    btnNew   = document.getElementById('new'),
    output   = document.getElementById('output'),
    feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');

// Emit events
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
   socket.emit('chat', {
      message: message.value,
      handle: handle.value
   });
});

message.addEventListener('keypress', function() {
   socket.emit('typing', handle.value);
});

// Listen for events
socket.on('chat', function(data) {
   feedback.innerHTML = ""
   output.innerHTML += '<p><strong>' + data.handle + ':</strong>' + data.message + '</p>'
});

// Emit 'is typing'
socket.on('typing', function(data) {
   feedback.innerHTML = '<p><em>' + data + ' is typing a message...</em></p>'
});
```

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>WebSockets 101</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div id="mario chat">
      <div id="chat-window">
         <div id="output"></div>
         <div id="feedback"></div>
      </div>
      <input id="handle" type="text" placeholder="Handle">
      <input id="message" type="text" placeholder="Message">
      <button id="send">Send</button>
      <button id="new">New</button>
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/chat.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that a post request will probably work as well, but if you want to simply work with socket.io you can consider doing something similar to your chat event by adding this in your `chat.js`:

```
btnNew.addEventListener('click', function() {
   socket.emit('new user', socket.id);
});
```

And on the server side, `app.js`:

```
socket.on('new user', function(id) {
   userQueue.push(id);
});
```

And it should be stored in the array. Hope this helps!

Comment: you're welcome :) a note of advice though: if you only want the id to be added once to the array remember to check whether it already exists in the array/disable the button after the first click event!